# Should I seed randint function in random package in python?

Tags: python, random

I want to check if the `randint` function is already seeded.

Should I manually seed it? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py#L748

Comment: Try to call `randint` without manually seedig it. If it works then you know it's already seeded.

Comment: You should seed it with a constant in case you need the pseudo-random numbers to be repeatable for each run. Otherwise, the module will use the current time as the seed value.

Comment: FTR: I didn't downvote this question as *this isn't explicitly documented*. It is instead assumed the reader understands RNG operations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to explicitly seed, unless you have very specific requirements. The internal `Random()` instance is automatically seeded the first time you import the module.

From the [module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html):

> The functions supplied by this module are actually bound methods of a hidden instance of the random.Random class.

and the [`Random.__init__()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.2/Lib/random.py#L87-L94):

> ```
> class Random(_random.Random):
>     # ...
>     def __init__(self, x=None):
>         # ...
>         self.seed(x)
>
> # ...
>
> _inst = Random()
> ```

so the instance calls `self.seed(None)` when the module is created. `None` means 'best available source of a seed' (which may be `time.time()`), see [`random.seed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed):

> If *a* is omitted or `None`, the current system time is used (together with the PID of the process). If randomness sources are provided by the operating system, they are used instead of the system time (see the [`os.urandom()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom) function for details on availability).